# Assign value to variable using popup edit text on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a popup box with edit text field on Android Studio and would like to store the data entered by the user in a variable used in that class. 
Something like this:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("New player")
                .setMessage("Input new player's name")
                .setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton("Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        name = input.getText().toString(); //<---HERE !want to use this variable
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .show();
```

This doesn't work, so how could I extract the value of `name` from my popup window to use it in the main code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
final String[] name = new String[1];
final EditText input = new EditText(this);

 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("New player")
        .setMessage("Input new player's name")
        .setView(input)
        .setPositiveButton("Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               name[0] = input.getText().toString(); <---HERE! want to use this variable 
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
         .show();
```

Access it using `name[0]`

**Clarification for the followup question by Jox in the comment below:** To access the variable inside `onClick` it needs to be `final`. But, you cannot assign a value to a simple final variable. However, you can assign a value to a Array member. Hence, the array and not a string variable. Btw, **Andriod Studio will do it for you this way itself**, just follow the suggested fixes for erroring-out code.

Comment: There is no reason to use an array for this.

Comment: you cannot assign value to a final variable but you can do it to an array. And to use it inside the onClick() it needs to be final.

Comment: @JoxTraex I'll be happy to learn a better and simpler alternative. Do let me know if you know one. What you see above is what Android Studio suggests btw. :)

Comment: Take a look at my post

Comment: Is that simpler? Dont think so :)

Comment: but if I insert, for example, a toast, after that code, it doesn't wait on the user to insert the data, it just gives a blank message.

Comment: make the toast inside onclick immediately after you assign the value.

Comment: but if I do somethin like this:

[code]
.show();
        
        grupo.insertPlayer(name[0]);
        group.draw(name[0]);


[code]

it runs the insertPlayer and draw methods before the user enters the name, and I can't call these method from the onCLick in the alertDialogue

Comment: if you need the name before those actions, you'll need to make them wait by either moving them to a method and calling it again in onclick or get the name in the previous screen.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how alert dialog works. It is really impatient and does not wait for anyone. I'd had that trouble once and got rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the DialogInterface.OnCLickListener inside of your Activity. By either creating a listener and assingning it or having your activity implement the interface. And then you won't need to declare name as final.

The reason you have to declare name as final is because you're anonmously creating an object to listen to the click, which require a contract of anything external being used by this anonymous class must be declared as final.

I would recommend creating a listener in your Activity and then assign it to the setOnClickListener(x)

Comment: Hi Jox. I'm new to studio. How would the code look like? Not sure on how to declare that.

Comment: Hence, not simple ... just kidding

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me :

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private EditText input;

    private String str = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        input = new EditText(this);
    }

    public void onClickAlert(View v) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("New player")
                .setMessage("Input new player's name")
                .setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton("Register", this)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .show();

        //variable str still equal to "" here
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        str = input.getText().toString(); /*<---HERE! want to use this variable*/
        //use it here
        Log.d("Activity", "User input : " + str);
    }
}
```

Implement the `OnClickListener` in your Activity and read the value of the text field in the callback fonction.